# React Native Expo: How to protect secret keys like Google Maps key?

Tags: react-native, expo, secret-key

We can't store the secret keys in the app code as they can be easily extracted by hackers.

One way is to get them from a backend service but my app works without authentication (guest user), so anyone with the backend url can get the keys which is not safe.

Another way is to use Attestation libraries but they need the app to be ejected to bare workflow. I want the solution in Expo managed workflow.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud (Google map in your case) provide various restriction options for both mobile apps and website with package name or website.

You can restrict apps that can use an API key.

https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices#application-restriction

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's not restricted to Google Maps, I have other secret keys as well like OAuth secret salt, geocoding key, Google places API key etc. The question is how can we restrict the keys from outside world.